# Trigonometry in nth partial sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

I am doing some nested regular polygon fractals for fun. 
I need to solve this sum for the $n$th partial sum to move forward with the exploration:

$$\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)-\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)}$$

The partial sum will tell me the sum of all the sides for each polygon with $n$ sides. I arrived at this problem after substituting the closed-form of an infinite geometric series with $a$ equal to $\dfrac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}$ and $r$ equal to $\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)$. I am completely lost at this stage.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts

Comment: Ok thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Damn I have to learn math Jax right now lol

Comment: What is the range of your sum?  Are you looking for something like $\sum_{k=1}^n1/(\cos(\pi/k)-\cos^2(\pi/k))$?

Comment: I’m looking for the nth partial sum, I’ll try using that thing you suggested and see where it gets me

Comment: I can’t add a picture because my reputation is so low.

Comment: Ok I got it to display finally! Thanks Jair!

Comment: @DerivingDrunk I will give you +1 for the username.

Comment: Yay! Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if a closed form would exist.

What you could do is to write
$$S_n=\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)-\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)}=\left(12+2 \sqrt{2}+\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}+2 \sqrt{5}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=7}^n  \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2 k}\right) \sec \left(\frac{\pi }{k}\right)$$ now develop the summand as a Taylor series. This would give
$$\csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2 k}\right) \sec \left(\frac{\pi }{k}\right)=\frac{4 k^2}{\pi ^2}+\frac{7}{3}+\frac{61 \pi ^2}{60 k^2}+\frac{631 \pi ^4}{1512
   k^4}+\frac{7321 \pi ^6}{43200 k^6}+\frac{91411 \pi ^8}{1330560
   k^8}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{10}}\right)$$ Now, you can sum from $7$ to $n$ to get for
$$T_n=\sum_{k=7}^n  \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2 k}\right) \sec \left(\frac{\pi }{k}\right)$$ a quite simple expression where appear a constant, a cubic polynomial in $n$ and a few generalized harmonic numbers. For sure, if $n$ is large, you can expand again the result using the asymptotics of the generalized harmonic numbers.

This would give, as an approximation for large $n$
$$S_n=-\frac{361}{498}+\frac{2 n^3}{3 \pi ^2}+\frac{n^2}{\pi ^2}+\left(\frac{7}{6}+\frac{1}{3 \pi ^2}\right)
   n-\frac{61 \pi ^2}{120 n}+\frac{61 \pi ^2}{240 n^2}-\frac{\pi ^2 \left(3843+3155
   \pi ^2\right)}{45360 n^3}+\frac{631 \pi ^4}{6048 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

For a small value such as $n=10$, the exact value is $88.4757$ while the approximation gives $88.4759$. For $n=100$, the exact value is $68679.9368097$ while the approximation gives $68679.9368107$.

Comment: Thank you! I spent 8 hours searching for a closed form solution both on my own and with consultation from others so this is kind of disheartening, but a good experience nonetheless.